# How to use Uipickerview controller Mapview

Tags: xcode5

I want to use the picker view to controller map view location,
e.g pickerview keyword is New York, then the mapview will search New York location in the map.

i don't know how to link these two view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598271/how-do-i-reload-refresh-the-uipickerview-with-new-data-array-based-on-button-p

Comment: i want to use pickerview to show plist dictionary>array>dictionary>string, then the mapview can show the location.