# IOS swift UIPickerview issue

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uipickerview

How can I add other picker view in my view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var UnitTypeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var UnitTypeSelectBTN: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var UnitTypePicker: UIPickerView!




    let UnitDataArray = ["Unit for Weight","Unit for Length","Unit for Area","Unit for Volume","Unit for Quantity"]
    let UnitforLengthData = ["m","km","cm","mm","yd","ft","in"]
    let UnitforWeightData = ["g","kg","m.t","l.t","sh.t","lb"]


    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return UnitDataArray.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return UnitDataArray[row]
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        return UnitTypeLabel.text = UnitDataArray[row]
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //UnitTypePicker.hidden = true
        UnitTypePicker.delegate = self
        UnitTypePicker.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it should be, you have to implement pickerView viewForRow method to achieve this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    let UnitDataArray = ["Unit for Weight","Unit for Length","Unit for Area","Unit for Volume","Unit for Quantity"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // pickerView delegate n dataSource
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return UnitDataArray.count
    }

    //MARK: Delegates
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return UnitDataArray[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView
    {
        var pickerLabel = UILabel()
        pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        pickerLabel.text = UnitDataArray[row]
        if let pickerViewFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 30) {
            pickerLabel.font = pickerViewFont
        }
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        return pickerLabel
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40.0
    }
}
```

Comment: if I want add two pcikerview , may i can just add second array, but how it.

Comment: If you want to have two pickerView's you have to create the second pickerView in storyboard, then drag it to IBOutlet and then change your delegates like this: 
`func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
     if pickerView == youFirstPickerViewIBOutlet { 
          return UnitDataArray.count
     } else {
          return ArrayForTheSecondPickerView.count
     } 
}`
You should do the same with titleForRow and viewForRow methods.

Comment: can i using IBAction to switch picker view or need using IBOutlet : UIButton

Comment: What did you mean under 'switch picker view'? You want to have two picker view in your window or only one and switch its data by button press?

Comment: Sorry , only one and switch its data by button press

Comment: Then create an `IBAction` for your button and create a `bool variable` equals to `false`. In you `IBAction` function write: 
`yourBoolVariable = !yourBoolVariable`
`pickerView.reloadAllComponents()`.
And in your pickerView delegates return or set your data according to your bool variable. If your variable == false, return or set your data for first array, if true - return or set your data for second array.
Tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more number of pickerView then you will have to set those number of components in it like this:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {
    return 2  //number of pickerViews
  }
```

By changing the number, you can set those number of pickerView in same viewController.

But if you want to change only dataSet for only one pickerView after any action then you can see this [How do I reload/refresh the UIPickerView (with new data array) based on button press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598271/how-do-i-reload-refresh-the-uipickerview-with-new-data-array-based-on-button-p)

Comment: but if return 2 will show 2 row in one pickerView, right?